# Finding the confidence level and number of successes

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that the sample size is $1500$ and the confidence interval of $p$ is $(0.050, 0.083)$. Find the confidence level and the number of successes.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  How would you find a confidence interval for $p$ if you observed $k$ successes from a sample size of $n$?

Comment: would it be like this: 
$E = Z * \sqrt{{p*{1-p}}/{n}}$
where Z is the Z value for $\alpha/2$ ?

Comment: I'm confused at to what p would be here though? Is it in between 0.050 and 0.083?

Comment: I worked it out that way and got a confidence level of 0.01, is that right? If so, where do I go from here to find number of successes

Comment: Did you mean the confidence interval is something like $\hat p \pm z_{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\hat p \left(1 - \hat p \right)}$ ? If so, then $\hat p$ is probably close to the midpoint of $(0.050, 0.083)$, though you can only observe an integer number of successes

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (had a little trouble with the code). This was my work for what I got: 
$E=Z_{1-\alpha/2}∗\sqrt{(p∗({p-1}))/n}$ 


Where $p$ is the center of the given interval, so $p = (0.050+0.083)/2 = 0.0665$


Also, the error $E$ as the difference of the midpoint and the endpoint of the interval so $E=0.0665-0.050=0.0165$ 


Plugging this into the equation I got that 
$0.0165=Z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sqrt{((0.0665)(1-0.0665))/1500}$ 


Solving for $Z_{1-\alpha/2}$ gives $Z_{1-\alpha/2}=2.56$ and since $Z_{2.96} = 0.99$ 


$Z_{1-\alpha/2} = 0.01$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that $n=1500$ and that $$ p \pm z_{α/2}\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}=(0.050,0.083)\tag{1}$$ where $\hat p=\frac{x}{n}$ the sample proportion. $x$ denotes the number of successes. Using only the symmetry of the confidence interval we may conclude that $$\hat p=\frac{0.050+0.083}{2}=0.0665\implies \frac{x}{n}=0.0665\implies x=0.0665\cdot1500=99.75$$ and rounded to the closest integer (number of successes cannot be a fractional number, it must be an integer) you have that $x=100$. Moreover, again by symmetry, $(1)$ yields that \begin{align}0.083-0.050=2z_{α/2}\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}&\implies z_{a/2}=0.0165\sqrt{\frac{1500}{0.0665(1-0.0665)}}\\[0.2cm]&\implies z_{α/2}\approx 2.57\end{align} From a table of the normal distribution you can infer that $α/2=0.005\implies α=0.01$ or $1\%$.

Comment: Thank you very much Jimmy and Henry! I think I understand this better now!